# Peroxide without hydrogen

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, solutions, ions

How come we always see hydrogen peroxide and never peroxide by itself. Is there such a thing as peroxide ? Does this exist in nature? Why is hydrogen always associated with it? Please note: First semester chem student so new to all this. Thanks!

Comment: Are you interested in how abundant free $\ce{O2^{2-}}$ in nature, or is there any hydrogen-free peroxides at all?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this can be answered with simple Google search.

Answer (score 3):

Well the peroxide can exist in the nature but it wouldn't be very stable. 
In fact ,You could look up the 2015 Nobel Prize owner of medicine.
She actually discover a substance called Artemisinin. 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artemisinin 
As the structure of this substance shows that it presents an peroxide bridge bond , which is normally unstable in the nature. But in this case, she also discovered that when this substance heats up, this substance will be stable instead of breaking up. There are also some of the substances that contains peroxide bridge bond. Additionally, the peroxide bridge is also believed to be one of the drug's mechanism.
Hope this helps!